# Semantic UI React Dropdown Obscures Search Box

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

I’m developing a react application where I use a Semantic UI React Dropdown where the user can search for and select a time zone. Programmatically the dropdown works fine. Except that dropdown list obscures the dropdown’s search box. See picture below. How can I reposition the dropdown list?

[image]

```
  <Grid.Column width={8}>
    <div style={styleDropdownDiv}>
      <Dropdown
        placeholder='Time Zones'
        search
        selection
        fluid
        options={timeZonesDropdownData}
        value={this.state.diveSiteTimeZoneID}
        onChange={this.onTimeZoneChange}
      />
    </div>
  </Grid.Column>


const styleDropdownDiv = {
  padding: '0px',
  marginTop: '15px'
};
```

Comment: Have you tried removing `padding` rule from your `styleDropdownDiv` styling?

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in a div with those styles? - you can apply apply styles directly to the Dropdown if necessary e.g. <Dropdown style={{ marginTop: '15px' }} />

Comment: Thanks Siavas and Scott … I've removed the div and inserted Dropdown style={{ marginTop: '15px' }} as suggested by Scott. But alas … no change... The dropdown list continues to obscure the dropdown’s search box.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved … it had nothing to do with the Dropdown, but rather with the react-datetime component displayed on the left side. It came with css which I modified that conflicted with the Dropdown.